# Uniform Asymptotic Approximation of the Whittaker function

Tags: special-functions, asymptotics, hypergeometric-functions

I would like to know if there exist a uniform asymptotic approximation of the Whittaker function $W_{\kappa,i\mu}(x)$ for $\kappa<0$, $x >0$, and with $\mu \to +\infty$. The case of $\kappa \ge 0$ is treated in [1], but I was not able to find the asymptotics for negative $\kappa$ in the literature.

[1] T. M. DUNSTER, Anal. Appl., 01, 199 (2003).